# Deploying nodejs files on shared hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, shared-hosting

1. In PHP I used to place files in public_html folder. I did the same for nodejs and started my application using "forever start app.js". Routers worked as expected, but I can able to see my nodejs source codes in the browser e.g. http://example.com/app.js showed the source code of app.js.
2. In some tutorials, They placed the files in /var/www/html/ and started the application. What's the difference between public_html and /var/www/html?
3. I'm using shared hosting, so I don't have permissions to place the files in /var/www/html/. I deployed nodejs files in /home/%username% folder and visited http://example.com/app.js. This time source codes are not visible and router thrown 404 error page as expected. (Deleted files in public_html before deploying in /home/%username%)
4. The index page router didn't work as expected. Instead of '/' or '/index', router received '/index.html.var' for the index page (http://example.com/).

Please guide me on deploying nodejs app securely on shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Er, no, Node.js is different, it's not PHP. A programme in Node.js is just like C/C++, Python, or any other general purpose programming language, it can control (likely) the whole server, so it's not to be deployed onto shared hosting.

You will need a cheap VPS (virtual private server, cloud server) at least, very cheap nowadays, on a par with shared hosting.

For starting, I suggest Heroku, free server: https://www.heroku.com

Programming notes:
Node.js is server-side language, it doesn't run in browser like traditional JS, you won't visit it by URL, unless you create a webserver using Express.js or that kind of library.

**Example using Express.js to server static files in public_html**:

- Put your server.js (or app.js, or whatever you put) outside public_html, don't put your Node.js code there.
- For example when you put your `app.js` right outside `public_html`, serve static files this way:

  `app.use('/static', express.static('public_html'))`
- Access your files at URL paths starting with `/static`, or use the following middleware use to server static files at root URL path.:

  `app.use('/', express.static('public_html'))`

Reference: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Ya got it. I thought deploying nodejs on public_html, the express router will take care of hiding my source code and serves only static files but that's not true it serves all the files in public_html. 
In VPS, where should I have to deploy nodejs?  (Which directory?)
Why '/' or '/index' page is received as '/index.html.var' in express router?
 app.use('/',index) // didn't worked
app.use('/index.html.var',index) //this served index page e.g. (http://example.com/)

Comment: got it. 
For Index Page, express router is getting "GET /index.html.var" instead of '/' or '/index'.
I logged using morgan module and got "GET /index.html.var" when I navigate to the homepage.
Can someone help me to fix this?